# module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'numpy_function'

Tags: python, tensorflow

module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'numpy_function'
on running

```
tf.numpy_function(lambda x: x, [tf.zeros([5])], [tf.float32])
```

I tried reinstalling tensorflow by pip install --force-reinstall tensorflow-gpu still the problem persists.
During installation I got this message:

```
  Found existing installation: wrapt 1.10.11
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'wrapt'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Comment: tf.version = '1.13.1'

Comment: [It is introduced from 1.14](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function).